# String concatenation always starts with undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to convert the elements in an array to string by placing `-` for each item whenever I add or remove an element in an array. This is how I implemented it:

```
onSelect(event: MatOptionSelectionChange, service: string) {
    let serviceList: string;
    if(event.source.selected) {
      this.servicesToToggle.push(service);
    } else {
      this.servicesToToggle = this.servicesToToggle.filter(item => item !== service);
    }

    this.servicesToToggle.forEach(element => {
      if(element === undefined) {
        return;
      }
      serviceList += '-' + element;
    });
    console.log(serviceList);
  }
```

The problem is the `undefined` gets included at the beginning of every string. like this:

```
undefined-Hardware Service 
undefined-Hardware Service-RFID Service
undefined-Hardware Service 
undefined-Hardware Service-RFID Service
undefined-Hardware Service-RFID Service-QR Service 
undefined-Hardware Service-RFID Service 
undefined-RFID Service undefined
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you aren't initializating the `serviceList` variable.

A declared and not initialised variable has the `undefined` value.

```js
var x;

console.log(x); // undefined
```

If you use the `+` operator between `undefined` and a string, the `undefined` will be coerced to the string `"undefined"`:

```js
var x;

console.log(x + 'foo'); // undefinedfoo
```

To solve it, initialise `serviceList` as empty string:

```
let serviceList: string = '';
```

I answer to your comment's question too.

There are a lot of ways to concatenate a list of strings, my favorite is to use `.join`:

```js
var concatenated = ['list', 'of', 'elements'].join(' - ');
console.log(concatenated);
```

In your case, it would be:

```
serviceList = this.servicesToToggle.join('-');
```

Another solution, if you prefer, could be a check on the index, we don't put `-` if `index === 0`:

```
this.servicesToToggle
.filter(Boolean) // removes null, undefined and empty strings
.forEach((element, index) => {
  const separator = index === 0 ? '' : '-';
  serviceList += separator + element;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. If you can help more. When I use this I get the '-' on the first string. like this "-Hardware Service-RFID Service". Is there a way to remove the '-' on the first element?